Error installing visual studio | couldn't install microsoft.visualcpp.redist.14
As the title states, i'm facing an issue while installing visual studio "couldn't install microsoft.visualcpp.redist.14".
I understand there are solutions here and there but they don't seem to resolve the issue for myself.
Version: 17.10.5
(https://i.sstatic.net/Apq60d8J.png)
logs:
*Something went wrong with the install.
You can troubleshoot the package failures by:
1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.
Package 'Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14,version=14.40.33810,chip=x86' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2147023274
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14,version=14.40.33810,chip=x86\VCRedistInstall.ps1""" -PayloadDirectory """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14,version=14.40.33810,chip=x86""" -Architecture x86 -Logfile """C:\Users\Ali Ebrahim\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20240810225729_232_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.log"""; exit $LastExitCode"
        Return code: -2147023274
        Return code details: Error opening installation log file. Verify that the specified log file location exists and that you can write to it.
    Log
        C:\Users\Ali Ebrahim\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20240810225729_232_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.log
    Impacted workloads
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=17.10.34803.213,productarch=x64)
        .NET Multi-platform App UI development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=17.10.34803.213)
    Impacted components
        .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=17.10.34803.213)
        .NET MAUI (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Maui.All,version=17.10.34803.213)
        .NET MAUI development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Maui.Shared,version=17.10.34803.213)
        .NET profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=17.10.34803.213)
        Blazor support for .NET MAUI Applications (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Maui.Blazor,version=17.10.34803.213)
        C# and Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=17.10.34803.213)
        Development tools for .NET (Microsoft.NetCore.Component.DevelopmentTools,version=17.10.34803.213)
        F# language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp,version=17.10.34803.213)
        GitHub Copilot (Component.VisualStudio.GitHub.Copilot,version=0.2.894.62884)
        Live Share (Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare.2022,version=1.0.5919)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=17.10.34803.213)
*

I have tried the following:

Installing SDK separately
Installing redistributable manually
uninstalling visual studio (Deleted all related files) and reinstalling
installing MAUI templates through CMD

None of them seem to resolve the issue.
Your help will be very appreciated :)

You can run InstallCleanup.exe to remove all installed Visual Studio instances completely and then try again.
If it doesn’t work, you could have a try with the following steps:
1.Manually delete any leftover install and cache folder you previously installed to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
%programdata%\Microsoft\visualstudio\packages

2.Delete the setup registry key, which was set when you first installed:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup

